# Playing .wav files in queue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue, wav

Trying to play .wav files in a thread safe queue. Calls may be triggered at random by any thread but must play in sequence. Problem is when I call `Play(string[] files)` with say 3 file names (currently testing from the UI thread), the last file is played 3 times, and the two first never played.  Can't see what causes this..?

Would appreciate suggestion for easier way to do this, but mainly like to know why this doesn't work.

```
public class Audio
{
    static ActionQueue actionQueue;
    public static string MediaFolder { get; set; }
    private static object syncroot = new object();

    static Audio()
    {
        actionQueue = new ActionQueue();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Plays .wav in async queue. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    public static void Play(string fileName)
    { 
        actionQueue.Add(() => PlaySound(fileName));
    }

    public static void Play(string[] files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID0: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        foreach (string f in files.ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queue file: " + f);
            actionQueue.Add(() => PlaySound(f));
        }
    }

    private static void PlaySound(string f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID1: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        var fileName = f;

        Console.WriteLine("Play queue: " + fileName);

        fileName = Path.Combine(MediaFolder, fileName);

        if (!Path.HasExtension(fileName))
            fileName = fileName + ".wav";

        if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        if (ext != ".wav") return;

        Console.WriteLine("Playing: " + fileName);

        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
        player.PlaySync();
    }
}

public class ActionQueue
{
    private  BlockingCollection<Action> persisterQueue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();     

    public  ActionQueue( )
    { 
        var thread = new Thread(ProcessWorkQueue);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private   void ProcessWorkQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var nextWork = persisterQueue.Take(); 
            nextWork();  
        }
    }

    public  void Add(Action action)
    { 
        persisterQueue.Add(action ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the classic [captured-loop-variable-in-a-closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop) problem.

You need to take a copy of your loop variables i.e.

```
    foreach (string f in files.ToList())
    {
        var copy = f;
        Console.WriteLine("Queue file: " + f);
        actionQueue.Add(() => PlaySound(copy));
    }
```

the reason being your delegates being passed to `actionQueue` are not executed until the loop has finished. By that time, of course, the variable `f` has changed value.